# Binded Value is different from displayed value

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I 'm having trouble with binded value and displayed value.

I'm using component like this;

```
<UDataGrid [(ItemsSource)]="Items">

 private _items = [];
    @Input() set Items(arg: any) {
        alert("Items set");
        this._items = arg;
    }
    get Items(): any {
        // other logic
        return this._items;
    }
```

When I call different component, do some stuff and going back to previous component, Items is getting null.

Even though it's getting null, I do not see any alert in screen.

Is there any way to understand how it's getting empty/null ?

Other problem is that, after Items is filled. I called DetectChanges().

Displayed value is different than the Items.

Is there anyway to track why DetectChanges is not worked ?

Comment: how do you pass the value from parent component to child to set the value in `this._items`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand the question.  There is no assignment for this._items. I just filled this.Items which set this._items

Comment: Do you pass in the same array when you get back? Angular might not see that your array has changed due to reference equality.

Comment: Actually, I'm not passing any array. There tabs in web page. Each tab is different component. I lost the information (where UDataGrid lives) when I came back to previous tab. The real problem is that in debug Items look empty but I still see Items in the screen. this.cdr.detectChanges() did not work too.